# Problem when importing my Unity project into my Native App

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, arcore

So I've imported my Unity project into my Android Native App and I'm facing the following problem when I'm trying to launch the Unity Activity.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.vmanordic.vrkarbala, PID: 4734
              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation
 found for void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRestartActivityIndicator()  (tried Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRestartActivityIndicator and Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRestartActivityIndicator__)
```

No implementation found for void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRestartActivityIndicator()

Has somebody else faced this issue, know any solution?

I'm launching the Activity with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), UnityPlayerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

I'm testing on a OnePlus 6 running Android P

Comment: I've tried changing the Intent but no result...

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), UnityPlayerActivity.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), REQUEST_CODE_UNITY_ACTIVITY, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Backend scripting to "IL2CPP" in player settings. 
Also, in target architectures, add ARM64. 
I had similar problem - I confirmed my Unity app was working in x86 processor phones (tried on HTC One E8) but did not work on 64bit architecture devices (tried Nokia 6.1).